# Why was this question pushed to the close vote review queue 8 months after being flagged as a duplicate?

Tags: support, review-queues

I have just reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/14444556) close vote review item. I noticed something odd about it: the question was pushed to the review queue about an hour ago, but the "possible duplicate" comment was posted 8 months ago. After further investigation I found out that short time after being flagged as a duplicate, it was pushed to the review queue, but no one reviewed it and it was invalided after four days at midnight (so it looks like it was automated). It seems reasonable to push the question to the review queue again if it hasn't been reviewed by anyone the last time. I was just wondering if this behavior is documented somewhere.

Comment: Probably someone flagged again. If the proposed target is already linked in a comment, another one isn't added. Questions aren't pushed into CVQ spontaneously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previous duplicate flag from March 2nd, 2016 aged away after it wasn't properly reviewed by the close queue.  Today, it was pushed back into the close queue because of a new duplicate flag. As [zaq mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338699/why-was-this-question-pushed-to-the-close-vote-review-queue-8-months-after-being#comment416476_338699) another comment wasn't added to the question about it being a duplicate because one was already present.